# Saving frequently updated arrays to database

Tags: python, json, database, tensorboard

I am creating a machine learning app which should save a number to a database **locally** and **frequently**.
These number values are connected which basically means that I want to frequently update a time series of values by **appending** a number to the list.

An ideal case would be to be able to save key-value pairs where key would represent the name of the array (example train_loss) and value would be according time series.
My first idea was leveraging **redis** but as far as I know redis data is only saved in RAM? What I want to achieve is saving to a disk after every log or perhaps after every couple of logs.

I need the local save of data since this data will be consumed by other app (in javascript). Therefore some *JSON-like* format would be nice.
Using JSON files (and Python json package) is an option, but I believe it would result in an I/O bottleneck because of frequent updates.

I am basically trying to create a clone of a web app like Tensorboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A technique we use in the backend of hosted application for frequently used read/post api is to write to the Redis and DB at the same time and during the read operation we check if the key is available in the Redis and if it's not we read update it to the Redis and then serve it

Comment: The saving to a file case is what troubles me the most. Maybe my question is not phrased well. I am more concerned about which technology should I use for saving the data to a file. I can work around the data loading, writing is the bottleneck for me. Since the lists can scale up to million items in length.

Comment: MongoDB will be your go to solution because its native JSON key value storage and it's fast for reads and updates because of hash table kind of implementation .